# Android Touch event handling (framework)

Tags: android

I would like to get an idea on how the touch events are handled in Android framework code - the code flow from kernel layer to application layer.

`[kernel -> InputReader -> ... -> onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)]`

Also would like to know what is the parameter which helps to control the 'scrolling velocity' in different applications? Is it the quantity of 'pressure' on touch, or the scroll offset value obtained in `ACTION_SCROLL`?